# Get an ascx on a aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a UserControl that consists of a Parent and Child UserControls that is displayed on a aspx page. I need to get the instance of the Parent UserControls from the child controls. The Parent has a set of nested .net controls and in these nested controls the child UserControls are displayed so if I use this from a child UserControls

```
MyControl _myControl = (MyControl)this.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.FindControl("MyControl");
```

where (this) = the child control and (Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent) walks me back the tree to the real parent.

This will get me there but there just seems to be a better way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Errrm, as you demonstrated; that will work where there are 3 parents to that child node. That's ok - what I'm asking is, What are you actually trying to determine ?  If you need to find the top level object then you just loop until `(this.Parent == null) == true`

Comment: reason I'm asking is because .Net normally ensures the .child and .parent hierarchy

Comment: I am using a RadPanel from teleric as a workflow control. So as the user completes panel1 I need to open panel2 with the next usercontrol. So the button for "next" is on the child control I need to go back up the tree to the RadPanel control so I can activate the next panel. what I am doing is similar to http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/panelbar/examples/applicationscenarios/accessingnestedcontrols/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `ascx` shouldn't know anything about its parent(s): that's a sign that it's too closely coupled to other classes. They might as well be one class.

One alternative is to follow the [law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter): figure out what `this` (your user control) needs from `MyControl`, make it a property, and let your aspx provide it rather than asking for it.

Comment: Sorry but how does this actually help in the question context ?

Comment: Changing the design in this way will make both `MyControl` and the `this` in question easier to use (the requested 'better way').

Comment: I agree with the statement as well. The Parent UserControl was originally a aspx to display in a popup window. All of the UserControls now that I think about it could be made into one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a master page, you can start from there and use the container id to find the control. It just depends what the control is closer to.

This might help:
http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs

Another thing you can do if you're accessing a value from a control in a parent page, is to put that value into the HttpContext.Current.Items["MyControlValue"] on page load. That way your usercontrol can grab that value easily

Comment: these UserControls are about in the middle so the first suggestion will be just as bad. I think I will give Number 2 a try.